# SQL Server - An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This way actually work in C#. But it does not work in SQL Server when executed:

```
Select 
    t3.MNAME + cast(t3.N as nvarchar) as 'کد دسته بندي',
    t3.NAME as 'شرح دسته',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 1 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'خريد',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 8 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'برگشت خريد',
    '' as 'حواله شعب',
    '' as 'برگشت شعب',
    '' as 'فروش',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 9 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'برگشت فروش',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 10 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ت کاردکس',
    sum(N1 - N2) as 'موجودي',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 4 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ح شعب',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 5 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ح ت شعب',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 6 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ب شعب',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 7 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ب ت شعب',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 2 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'ح ت فروش',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 3 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'فروش جزئي',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 12 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'فروش عادي',
    sum(case when t1.DT = 11 then t1.N1 - t1.N2 else 0 end) as 'برگشت فروش تعدادي' 
From 
    BC as t1, _TBS_TYPE as t3   
Where 
    substring(t1.BARCODE, 1, 1) = t3.MNAME 
    and substring(t1.BARCODE, 2, 1) = cast(t3.N as nvarchar)  
    and t3.MNAME + cast(t3.N as nvarchar) and t3.NAME  
group by 
    t3.MNAME, t3.N, t3.NAME 
order by 
    2, 3
```

Error :

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'and'.

Comment: Where substring(t1.BARCODE,1,1)=t3.MNAME and substring(t1.BARCODE,2,1)=cast(t3.N as nvarchar)  and t3.MNAME+cast(t3.N as nvarchar) Like '%", this.fieldTxt3.Text.Trim(), "%'   and t3.NAME Like '%", this.fieldTxt8.Text.Trim(), "%'  group by t3.MNAME,t3.N,t3.NAME order by 2,3 " })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below - without assigning some value you define a condition like - `and t3.MNAME + cast(t3.N as nvarchar) and t3.NAME`

Also, it is best to use explicit `JOIN`

```
Select t3.MNAME+cast(t3.N as nvarchar) as 'کد دسته بندي',
t3.NAME as 'شرح دسته',
sum(case when t1.DT = 1 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'خريد',
sum(case when t1.DT = 8 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'برگشت خريد',
''  as 'حواله شعب',
''  as 'برگشت شعب',
''  as 'فروش',
sum(case when t1.DT = 9 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'برگشت فروش',
sum(case when t1.DT = 10 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ت کاردکس',
sum(N1-N2) as 'موجودي' ,
sum(case when t1.DT = 4 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ح شعب',
sum(case when t1.DT = 5 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ح ت شعب',
sum(case when t1.DT = 6 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ب شعب',
sum(case when t1.DT = 7 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ب ت شعب',
sum(case when t1.DT = 2  then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'ح ت فروش',
sum(case when t1.DT = 3 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'فروش جزئي',
sum(case when t1.DT = 12 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'فروش عادي',
sum(case when t1.DT = 11 then t1.N1-t1.N2 else 0 end)  as 'برگشت فروش تعدادي' 
From BC as t1 inner join _TBS_TYPE as t3   
on substring(t1.BARCODE,1,1)=t3.MNAME and substring(t1.BARCODE,2,1)=cast(t3.N as nvarchar)  
group by t3.MNAME,t3.N,t3.NAME 
order by 2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

In Where condition filter right side of the value is missing in your code.

```
Where 
substring(t1.BARCODE, 1, 1) = t3.MNAME 
and substring(t1.BARCODE, 2, 1) = cast(t3.N as nvarchar)  
and t3.MNAME + cast(t3.N as nvarchar) and t3.NAME  -------->Missing code here
```